# Crypto++ low level AES API (a la SJCL)

Tags: javascript, c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

I'm trying to reverse engineer a protocol from a javascript implementation, and I'm stuck on an AES encryption method. I'm programming this in C++, with the Crypto++ library. It's using the SJCL library, and it calls `ciphertext = (new sjcl.cipher.aes(key)).encrypt(plaintext)`. From the SJCL documentation, I can see that this is a low-level interface. `ciphertext`, `key`, and `plaintext` are all 4-element arrays of 32-bit integers. As far as I know, and could find on google, Crypto++ only provides high-level interfaces. Is there any way to get Crypto++ to do what SJCL is doing? Also, what exactly does that `encrypt` method do?

http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.com/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.cipher.aes.html

Edit: I noticed the javascript code converted `plantext` from a string to ints, and I think I tried every combination of changing endianess of every variable. I tried all combinations that made sense, anyway. I also tried creating arrays of `int32_t`'s and initializing them with what was input into that line of javascript. Here's what I've got now:

```
void crypto()
{
    SecByteBlock key(16);
    int32_t plain[4] = { 0x93C467E3, 0x7DB0C7A4, 0xD1BE3F81, 0x0152CB56 }, cipher[4];
    int32_t* keyBuf = (int32_t*) key.BytePtr();

    keyBuf[0] = 1885434739;
    keyBuf[1] = 2003792484;
    keyBuf[2] = 0;
    keyBuf[3] = 0;

    cout << "plain = [" << plain[0] << ", " << plain[1] << ", " << plain[2] << ", " << plain[3] << "]\n";

    cout << "key = [" << keyBuf[0] << ", " << keyBuf[1] << ", " << keyBuf[2] << ", " << keyBuf[3] << "]\n";

    ECB_Mode<AES>::Encryption e;
    e.SetKey(key, key.size());

    StringSource((const byte*) plain, 16, true, new StreamTransformationFilter( e, new ArraySink((byte*)cipher, 16) ) );

    cout << "cipher = [" << cipher[0] << ", " << cipher[1] << ", " << cipher[2] << ", " << cipher[3] << "]\n";

}

function crypto()
{
    var key = [1885434739, 2003792484, 1885434739, 2003792484];
    var plain = [0x93C467E3,0x7DB0C7A4,0xD1BE3F81,0x0152CB56];
    console.log("plain = "+plain);
    console.log("key = "+key);
    var cipher = (new sjcl.cipher.aes(key)).encrypt(plain);
    console.log("cipher = "+cipher);
}
```

Here's the output of the C++ version:

```
plain = [2479122403, 2108737444, 3518906241, 22203222]
key = [1885434739, 2003792484, 1885434739, 2003792484]
cipher = [3437909595, 1341853431, 2532744872, 2416113380]
```

and JavaScript:

```
plain = 2479122403,2108737444,3518906241,22203222
key = 1885434739,2003792484,1885434739,2003792484
cipher = -1974659585,-1567997661,-1863224381,-318378846
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use the integers as big endian representation of byte arrays. So the highest byte should be to the left. Then you get 16 byte input/output, for 128 bit AES. You can use Crypto++ or other higher level cryptography libs in ECB mode to perform a block encrypt/decrypt.

Note that the SJCL `aes` class only implements the primitive. It is used within SJCL as implementation of one of the [ccm](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.com/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.mode.ccm.html) or [ocb2](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.com/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.mode.ocb2.html) modes of encryption. Those modes in turn are used by the convenience library, but - if I remember correctly - that one goes straight to using JSON encoding/decoding, which may be a step too far for you.

Comment: PS I have once created a library to simulate SJCL in Java, it is on Github. I've more or less abandoned it because I'm not sure I believe in one person cryptographic projects (as SJCL seems to be). E.g. I found that it did not perform any authentication on the additional associated data in the convenience library. It does not seem that any compatibility tests have been performed either and the JSON encoding has not been completely specified...

Comment: I tried changing the endianness, but no combination of changing the 3 variables' endianness worked.

Comment: Maybe ask Mike Hamburg in one of the forums or lists of SJCL? You should be able to reverse engineer it from how the counter mode encryption is used, but that is hard...

Comment: I've programmed it in Java, and used big endian notation. I got the JavaScript output without issue, but C++ generally uses little endian (depending on the target machine, of course, not so much the language itself).

Comment: Changed endianess and even bit order of the inputs, but to no avail. Tried to read the Crypto++ classes and methods, but I soon got frustrated by that godawful API.